# Is it possible to browse video hosted on ooyala directly by URL like YouTube?

Tags: ooyala

I need to share the URL of a video on Facebook and Twitter but some of the videos are hosted on ooyala. I didn't get any direct link for videos which are hosted on ooyala, like for videos that are hosted on YouTube.

How can we access the videos which are hosted on ooyala directly by URL like YouTube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooyala is not exactly like YouTube. It doesn't have a public-facing website to browse all the videos it stores. Ooyala provides video hosting, but every customer is in charge of displaying the video to the end users, so if, for example, Vice uploads an asset to it, the URL that you should use to share on social networks is the article on [vice.com](http://vice.com/) it belongs to.

Disclaimer: I work at Ooyala.

Comment: I have video_id and player_id only from backed so please guide the way how i can share it using Facebook and  Twitter is their need of any extra plugin. if you have any tutorial for reference please share.

Comment: You share the URL that the video was hosted on

Answer (score 2):

Niles, to address you comment about shared to Facebook; Ooyala recently released an updated Syndication method specifically to share videos directly to Facebook (as well as existing method to do the same direct sharing to Youtube)

Check out this link to learn more about how to syndicate directly to Facebook. http://support.ooyala.com/users/documentation/tasks/syndication_facebook.html